# Convertin XML to excel but leading zeroes are getting removed

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am converting XML to excel. I have ID whose values are 00003233 but after conversion to excel it is 3233. I have multiples XML files so I am using code to combine all different XML files. Below is the code.

```
Sub From_XML_To_XL()

    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
    xCount = 1
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml")
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)
        xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
        xWb.Close False
        xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2
        xFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    xSWb.Save
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Error"
End Sub
```

Comment: See: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/f0171590-a9e0-4174-a3ab-c51db08f2b0f/importing-xml-into-excel-data-formatting-help?forum=exceldev

Comment: Search this site for the exact phrase `[excel] import zero`. This question has been asked (and answered) many times before here.